# Emacs can't render 4-byte UTF-8?

Tags: emacs

I've got a JSON file that contains 1, 2, 3, and 4 byte UTF-8 encodings.  Emacs 26.1 (9.0) does OK with the 1, 2, and 3 byte encodings, but I get nothing but spaces for the 4-byte encodings.  I kind-of expected this to work out-of-the-box.  When I cat the file, it appears to be encoded fine.  Vim too has no problem with it (I get to see my 4 byte encodings).  Its only emacs that fails to render the 4 byte encodings.  The file in question is like...

```
{
  "samples": [
    {
      "description": "ASCII A, B, C",
      "unicodes": [ "U+0041", "U+0042", "U+0043" ],
      "data": "UTF-8_ABC"
    },
    {
      "description": "Cyrillic A, Be, Ve",
      "unicodes": [ "U+0410", "U+0411", "U+0412" ],
      "data": "UTF-8_АБВ"
    },
    {
      "description": "Dingbat Circle Sans-serif 7, 8, 9",
      "unicodes": [ "U+2786", "U+2787", "U+2789" ],
      "data": "UTF-8_➆➇➈"
    },
    {
      "description": "Emoji Carrot, Corn, Hot Pepper",
      "unicodes": [ "U+1F955", "U+1F33D", "U+1F336" ],
      "data": "UTF-8_"
    }
  ]
}
```

Emacs fails to render the carrot, corn, and red pepper.  Instead showing just really wide spaces.

How do I get emacs to render this correctly?

Interestingly enough, I saved this file with emacs with cut-and-paste of the various characters like https://emojipedia.org/ear-of-maize/

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I pasted your data into Emacs 26.1 and it shows all of those characters.  My **font** doesn't include the CARROT character, so I only see a place-holder for that (Emacs shows me a box containing the hex codepoint in very small text).

Comment: I've been using [this trick](https://github.com/legoscia/dotemacs/blob/master/dotemacs.org#fix-the-display-of-emoji) to force Emacs to use a convenient font for emojis.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @legoscia's config, I installed the Symbola font and added this to my config:

```
;; better font config for weird chars
(when (find-font (font-spec :name "Symbola"))
  (set-fontset-font t '(#x10000 . #x1ffff) "Symbola"))
```